# get required controllers into directives controller with bindToController

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm a big fan of the new (angular 1.3+) controllerAs and bindToController syntax. Right now I'm basically trying to remove all link functions in my directives. But how would I get required controllers into my directives' controller?

A working solution would be:

```
require : "ngModel",
scope : true,
bindToController : true,
link : function(scope, elem, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
    scope.ngModel = ngModelCtrl;
},
controller : function(..., $scope) {
    this.ngModel = $scope.ngModel;
}
```

I find this very ugly, especially as I need to reintroduce the scope and link function again. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

My way requireing the directives controller

```js
app.directive('psiLbUploadGallery', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: galleryTpl,
    require: ['psiLbUploadGallery', 'ngModel'],
    scope: {},
    controller: controller,
    controllerAs: 'PsiLbUploadCtrl',
    bindToController: {
      uploadUrl: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attrs, controllers) {
      let PsiLbUploadCtrl = controllers[0];
      let ngModelCtrl = controllers[1];

      PsiLbUploadCtrl.ngModel = ngModelCtrl;
    }
  };
});
```

export default class PsiLbUploadCtrl {

```
  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.ngModel);
    });
  }
}
```